# Commit all files in a folder to SVN repository using sharpsvn

Tags: winforms, svn, sharpsvn

I hava c# winforms application and in the form I have a button. On click of the button I want to commit all files in a particular folder to the **SVN** repository , but i keep getting

> Folder is not a working copy error.

Below code is called on click event:

```
private void Save_Config_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    #if DEBUG
    path = @"../../../Application";
    #endif

    using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
    {
        SvnCommitArgs args = new SvnCommitArgs();

        args.LogMessage = "test";
        args.ThrowOnError = true;
        args.ThrowOnCancel = true;

        try
        {
            client.Commit(path, args);

        }
        catch (Exception s)
        {
            if (s.InnerException != null)
        {
        throw new Exception(s.InnerException.Message, s);
     }

     throw s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Commit from a folder, that folder must be a [working copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html).
You must `checkout` before you make the `commit`.